# How to both define a js function in a separate file yet attach it to a QML element

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I can do this:

```
SomeElement{
    id: something
    function someFunction(){...}
....

OtherElement{
     property int whatever: something.someFunction()
```

However, I'd like all my JS functions defined in a separate file. The problem is that this decouples the functions from being attached to any one element, as far as I can tell. I can no longer refer to a function as a property on another element to call it.

Is it possible for a function to be attached to a QML element but still have it defined in another file? Would there be some syntax to "forward" or "alias" the function from the element so one could still call this "member function" on the element, and thus this function could be able to access other properties on its parent element?

Comment: I don't think it is currently possible to do this for now. You either have to add a wrapper in the component for your function or keep the function in your QML file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import js file as some module and use its function with module name prefix. So, they will be in separate 'namespace' from you QML object's functions

Documentation about it: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-javascript-imports.html

Comment: Yes but this won't allow calling the function outside of the component as if it was a function of the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for a function to be attached to a QML element but
>   still have it defined in another file? Would there be some syntax to
>   "forward" or "alias" the function from the element so one could still
>   call this "member function" on the element, and thus this function
>   could be able to access other properties on its parent element?

Not directly, but easily fake-able:

```
// foo.js
function printDimensions(item) {
    console.log(item.width, "x", item.height)
}

// in qml
import "foo.js" as Foo
// ..
Item {
  id: someItem
  function printDimensions() { Foo.printDimensions(someItem) }
}
// ..
Rectangle {
  id: anotherItem
  function printDimensions() { Foo.printDimensions(anotherItem) }
}
```

This way you can attach the function to different objects via a simple wrapper.